# AVX2 SIMD addition not working

Tags: c++, sse, simd, avx, avx2

I am trying to add this two vectors using AVX2 SIMD instruction.

The code compiles with no error & warning, but crashes when run.  Why?

It should print the result of SIMD addition with AVX2 no matter how large the array is which is initialized in the main method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;



void mul(float *a, float *b, float *c, int ARR_SIZE){

        for (int i=0; i < ARR_SIZE ; i+=8){

         __m256 vecA = _mm256_load_ps(&a[i]);

         __m256 vecB = _mm256_load_ps(&b[i]);

         __m256 res  = _mm256_add_ps(vecA,vecB);

         _mm256_store_ps(&c[i],res);

        float* f = (float*)&c[i];
        printf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f\n", f[i + 0], f[i + 1], f[i + 2], f[i + 3], f[i + 4], f[i + 5], f[i + 6], f[i + 7]);

        }

}

int main(){

    float a[] = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0};
    float b[] = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0};

    int arrsize = sizeof(a) / sizeof (a[0]);

    float c[arrsize];

    mul((float*)&a, (float*)&b , (float*)&c, arrsize);

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Try unaligned load/store (or sufficiently aligned arrays)

Comment: Try remove the ampersands: `mul((float*)a, (float*)b , (float*)c, arrsize);`

Comment: thanks harold. After trying your suggestion the program worked.

Comment: you had better to use `__attribute__(( aligned(32)))` or so to align the array instead of loading them unaligned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying both unaligned load & store the program worked perfectly.